# How can I make my Arduino Uno press Space on my laptop keyboard?

Tags: arduino-uno, keyboard

So I wanna build something which, when it receives a remote signal, presses the spacebar on my laptop keyboard. I tried using the Keyboard.press() but it is available only for Leonardo. Is there any way I can use it in my Uno, without having to mess with the firmware?

If not, what else can I use to accomplish my goal?

Comment: https://github.com/NicoHood/Hoodloader

Comment: @Majenko Are you sure this has no dangers at all?

Comment: You can do that without burn a new bootloader via an interface application. The disadvantage is that you have to code a new application. You can do that with Java, C++, C#, ... You can send a message through serial and received it with your app. Tha's not the best way.

Comment: you could send a signal character over serial ... run a Processing sketch on the laptop that generates a keypress everytime the signal character is received

Comment: Control a servo that physically presses the spacebar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows you can use a serial to keyboard redirector like [this one](http://www.priority1design.com.au/datasnip.html)

It can start with windows, Im using it for a long time without any issues.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you have some knowledge in Java or Python you can interface your Arduino board to PC, through Arduino's SerialPort.
When Arduino sends a byte, for example, 0xAB, your Java or Python script sends a fake key-press event.
I hope this can help. Good luck!

Comment: are you sure you can send a keypress event to any application from other application?